# Negative Indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am not exactly good at evaluating negative indices--can someone please show me how to work out this expression:
$$\frac {m^{-3}n^{-2}} {m^{-5}n^6} $$

Both $m$'s and the top $n$ have negative indices.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $-3-(-5)$, $-2-6$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $a^{-n}=\frac1{a^n}$
$$\frac {m^{-3}n^{-2}} {m^{-5}n^6}= \frac{m^5}{m^3n^6n^2}=\frac{m^2}{n^8}$$

Comment: So basically in a two part fraction, if there is a negative indice the base goes on the other side and the indice becomes positive?

Comment: @Kiwi: Yes exactly

Comment: Okay thanks so much @Roman83 !!

Answer (score 1):

Negative exponents:

$$m^{-3} = \frac{1}{m^3}$$

In the same way for the others and your expressions is nothing but

$$\frac{\frac{1}{m^3}\frac{1}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{m^5}n^6} = \frac{m^5}{m^3 n^2 n^6} = \frac{m^2}{n^8} = \left(\frac{m}{n^4}\right)^2$$

It's all about powers, exponents and their properties.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in a comment, I consider the best exercise here to use the fact that dividing powers subtracts the exponents, that is: $\frac{a^m}{a^n} = a^{m-n}$. So in this case:

$$\frac {m^{-3}n^{-2}} {m^{-5}n^6}  = m^{-3-(-5)}n^{-2-6} = m^{2}n^{-8} = \frac{m^2}{n^8}$$

Assuming that you can subtract negative numbers mentally, then you can usually forego writing the middle steps and just do the whole thing in one step. And if you can't, then that's a sign you need to practice basic operations on negative numbers some more.